# Quick way of transforming a datetime column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, lambda

I have a mountain of CSV's where the date column is the following:

```
Print df
           Date
0          20090501 00:00:00.831
1          20090501 00:00:00.832
2          20090501 00:00:01.078
3          20090501 00:00:01.337
4          20090501 00:00:01.580
5          20090501 00:00:01.581
6          20090501 00:00:01.582
7          20090501 00:00:01.602
```

From here I want to express it in the format `'%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f'`, hence:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print df
          Date
          2009-05-01 00:00:00.831
1         2009-05-01 00:00:00.832
2         2009-05-01 00:00:01.078
3         2009-05-01 00:00:01.337
4         2009-05-01 00:00:01.580
5         2009-05-01 00:00:01.581
```

And finally from there, split it into separate date and time columns using the following:

```
df['Time'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.time())
df['Date1']= df['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.date())
print df
         Time             Date1   
0        00:00:00.831000  2009-05-01
1        00:00:00.832000  2009-05-01
2        00:00:01.078000  2009-05-01
3        00:00:01.337000  2009-05-01
4        00:00:01.580000  2009-05-01
5        00:00:01.581000  2009-05-01
6        00:00:01.582000  2009-05-01
```

The problem is that the lambda functions take around one minute to complete, and I have something in the range of 30000 CSV's to process each with approximately two million rows. If anyone can give me a faster solution it would help a great deal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) and [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.time
df['Date1']= df['Date'].dt.date
print (df)
                     Date             Time       Date1
0 2009-05-01 00:00:00.831  00:00:00.831000  2009-05-01
1 2009-05-01 00:00:00.832  00:00:00.832000  2009-05-01
2 2009-05-01 00:00:01.078  00:00:01.078000  2009-05-01
3 2009-05-01 00:00:01.337  00:00:01.337000  2009-05-01
4 2009-05-01 00:00:01.580  00:00:01.580000  2009-05-01
5 2009-05-01 00:00:01.581  00:00:01.581000  2009-05-01
6 2009-05-01 00:00:01.582  00:00:01.582000  2009-05-01
7 2009-05-01 00:00:01.602  00:00:01.602000  2009-05-01
```

Comment: Shaved around 15 seconds off, not bad at all.

Comment: Super ;) This functions are vectorized, so faster as `apply`.